# Z3 Strings: finding the API

Tags: string, z3

[1] I've downloaded and installed Z3 4.5.0 from this GitHub repository:

```
https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3
```

[2] Next, I ran this command:

```
./build/z3 smt.string_solver=z3str3 -smt2 example.txt
```

[3] Where example.txt is:

```
(declare-const s1 String)
(declare-const s2 String)
(declare-const s3 String)
(declare-const s4 String)

(assert (= (str.len s1) 1))
(assert (= (str.len s2) 2))
(assert (> (str.len s4) 4))
(assert (= (str.++ s1 s2) s3))
(assert (str.contains s4 s3))

(check-sat)
(get-value (s1 s2 s3 s4))
```

[4] I got what I expected:

```
sat
((s1 "d")
 (s2 "af")
 (s3 "daf")
 (s4 "bdafaaaI"))
```

[5] However, I can not find the corresponding API Z3 string functions,
So I can build formulas incrementally from my C++ application.

I would expect something like:

```
z3_mk_concat(...)
z3_mk_str_contains(...)
etc.
```

But I couldn't find anything close ...

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings is a fairly new feature and it is being improved as we learn lessons from the current approaches. You will be much better off using the latest nightly build. There the C++ API contains support for string operations.